# Facebook Graph API v2.1 Upgrade Notice - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Today I have received notification from facebook saying this.

"MyAppName has been making recent API calls to Graph API v2.0, which will reach the end of the 2-year deprecation window on Monday, August 8, 2016. Please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to avoid potential broken experiences"

In my iOS app I am using facebook sdk v4.8.0. And when I calling the Graph API Request, I never specify a version

According to facebook API documentation, It says Graph API version is default to facebook sdk (In my app fbsdk:4.8 = grapgh api v2.5). So, why I get this notification. Should I consider to update the sdk at this point?

Comment: In my case I was making calls using url https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/ in my android app and confused it for iOS. I don't know if this is the case with you. You can check you are using url like this anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 2):

We can check our app is affected or not when the graph api 2.0 is deprecated. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog?hc_location=ufi

If your app doesn't need to make changes to account for the new version, then you don't need to do anything - probably worth changing the version you call explicitly and testing, though.

I have initiate a post asking this question in facebook developer community. Anyone can check the latests answers there.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1105482529495260/?comment_id=1105549489488564&notif_t=group_comment&notif_id=1466589917464742#